# Как сделать что бы текст не переносился?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

есть простой тестовый блок. Который имеет width 0 но при клике добавление класса у него появляется width 40%. Т.е на подобие плавное появление блока и за ширины( блок прикреплен к левой части) И все бы хорошо но когда нужно скрыть блок, видно что тест и за того что место мало, начинает сжиматься. Можно как то это предотвратить

Comment: Здравствуйте. Вы так здорово всё описали, а примера вашего кода разве у вас нет?

Answer (score 4):

Похоже, меня не услышали. Вам нужен `white-space:nowrap`

```js
$("input").on("input", (e) => {
  $(".parent").css("width", $(e.target).val() * 2 + "px")
});
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  background:red;
  width:40px;
}

.child {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Tenetur, deserunt!
  </div>
</div>

<input type="range" value=20>
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Нужно текст поместить в отдельный блок, а сжимать родительский. При этом ширину дочернего элемента нужно задать жестко.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Tenetur, deserunt!
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes roll-in {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
  }
}

.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: roll-in 2s linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;

}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ja6rv9/6/)

Comment: Егор в том то и проблема что в пкс не вариант))

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa Не понял, в чем не вариант?

Comment: Задать ширину в px

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa какой контекст? Как можно задавать ширину?

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa [тогда так](https://jsfiddle.net/n1ja6rv9/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё как вариант, смещать блок а не уменьшать. Но текст, должен быть обвёрнут в свой узел.

```js
function spoler(_e){
 if(_e == window){
  spoler(_e.event.target || _e.event.srcElement)
 }
 else if(_e.getAttribute("class")){
  _e.removeAttribute("class")
 }
 else{
  _e.setAttribute("class", "close")
 }
}
```

```css
DIV {
 position: relative; 
 border: #4a4a4a 3px solid; 
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
DIV SPAN {
 zoom:1; z-index: 1; position: relative; display:-moz-inline-stack; display: inline-block; //display: inline; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;
}
DIV.close {
 left: -60%;
}
DIV.close SPAN{
 margin-left: 60%;
}
```

```html
 <div onclick="spoler(this)"><span>есть простой тестовый блок. Который имеет width 0 но при клике добавление класса у него появляется width 40%. Т.е на подобие плавное появление блока и за ширины( блок прикреплен к левой части) И все бы хорошо но когда нужно скрыть блок, видно что тест и за того что место мало, начинает сжиматься. Можно как то это предотвратить</span>
  <span>следующий текстовый блок</span>
  </div>
  <div onclick="spoler(this)"><span>есть простой тестовый блок. Который имеет width 0 но при клике добавление класса у него появляется width 40%. Т.е на подобие плавное появление блока и за ширины( блок прикреплен к левой части) И все бы хорошо но когда нужно скрыть блок, видно что тест и за того что место мало, начинает сжиматься. Можно как то это предотвратить</span></div>
```